# clear textbox with image click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Seems like a simple thing to do, but not sure how to do it.

I have this ReadOnly textbox and it gets populated when the user clicks on a button and selects a value from a modal box. I need an other image_click that will clear the text box. Given below is the code I have, not sure how to have a simple image button click to do this.

The Html.SecurityTrimmedActionButton for the 'SearchButton' works fine. The problem I have is with the 'DeleteButton'. Do I need to have even the SecurityTrimmedAction here, since I really do not need to call any controller, I have the function to clear the textbox in the view itself. What can I use instead of the Html.SecurityTrimmedAction?

```
       <%: Html.TextBoxFor_Readonly(model => model.AdditionalEmailsSentTo, new { style    = "width:500px; height:40px;" })%>
        <%: Html.SecurityTrimmedActionButton(true, "Search Active Directory", "Index", "ActiveDirectory", "btnAdditionalEmailSearch", "clsSearchButton")%>
        <%: Html.SecurityTrimmedActionButton(true, "Clear AdditionalEmails", "Index", "ActiveDirectory", "btnRemoveAdditionalEmail", "clsDeleteButton")%>
```

Here is my script to clear the textbox

```
$("#btnRemoveAdditionalEmail").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#AdditionalEmailsSentTo").val("");   

        });
```

When clicked on the image, the entire text box along with the image buttons disappear.

Comment: @GazWinter what do you mean??  Didn't Op post that?

Comment: Could post the jQuery event handling code for `#btnAdditionalEmailSearch` ?

Comment: @dbaseman I think they edited the code while i was posting the comment.

Comment: @GazWinter, I had not formatted the code right and hence was not showing, had to edit it.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im the #btnAdditionalEmailSearch is working fine..I have problems with the Clearing the text and I've posted the script that I've written.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it was resolved

```
   <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.Label("Additional Email Address") %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor_Readonly(model => model.AdditionalEmailsSentTo, new {id="AdditionalEmailsSentTo", style = "width:500px; height:40px;" })%>
        <%: Html.SecurityTrimmedActionButton(true, "Search Active Directory", "Index", "ActiveDirectory", "btnAdditionalEmailSearch", "clsSearchButton")%>
        <button id='btnRemoveAdditionalEmailSearch' class='clsRemoveButton'>
            Clear Additional Emails</button>
    </div>
```

Here is my javascript function

```
      $("#btnRemoveAdditionalEmailSearch").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#AdditionalEmailsSentTo").val("");
        });
```

and the textbox was disappering because, I did not notice that the button clsDeleteButton was hooked to do that. A collegue discovered that and created an other one called clsRemoveButton.